# Configure an API Gateway method to inherit throttling settings from the stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, throttling

I'm using the AWS CLI `update-stage` command to configure specific throttling settings for an API Gateway method, which works fine:

```
aws apigateway update-stage --rest-api-id <the-id> --stage-name <the-stage-name>
--patch-operations op=replace,path='/~1cats~1{pawId}/GET/throttling/rateLimit',value=10
```

However, when I attempt to remove the setting I just configured and have the throttling settings be inherited from the stage, as is the default, I get an error:

```
aws apigateway update-stage --rest-api-id <the-id> --stage-name <the-stage-name>
--patch-operations op=remove,path='/~1cats~1{pawId}/GET/throttling/rateLimit'
```

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateStage operation:
Cannot remove method setting ~1cats~1{pawId}/GET/throttling/rateLimit because there
is no method setting for this method
```

How do I use the CLI (or the AWS SDK for that matter) to get the method to inherit settings from the stage again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is with the path for remove call. You are using "/~1cats~1{pawId}/GET/throttling/rateLimit".

API Gateway supports removing all the method settings and not just a particular methodSetting. I dropped "/throttling/rateLimit" from my remove call and it worked.

I ran following commands and it works

```
aws apigateway update-stage --rest-api-id <> --stage-name <> --patch-operations op=replace,path='/hw/GET/throttling/rateLimit',value=20
{
    "deploymentId": "<>",
    "stageName": "<>",
    "cacheClusterEnabled": false,
    "cacheClusterStatus": "NOT_AVAILABLE",
    "methodSettings": {
        "hw/GET": {
            "metricsEnabled": false,
            "dataTraceEnabled": false,
            "throttlingBurstLimit": 5000,
            "throttlingRateLimit": 20.0,
            "cachingEnabled": false,
            "cacheTtlInSeconds": 300,
            "cacheDataEncrypted": false,
            "requireAuthorizationForCacheControl": true,
            "unauthorizedCacheControlHeaderStrategy": "SUCCEED_WITH_RESPONSE_HEADER"
        }
    },
    "tracingEnabled": false,
    "createdDate": "2020-04-24T13:50:18-07:00",
    "lastUpdatedDate": "2020-04-27T01:21:45-07:00"
}
```

```
aws apigateway update-stage --rest-api-id <> --stage-name <> --patch-operations op=remove,path=/hw/GET,value=""
{
    "deploymentId": "<>",
    "stageName": "<>",
    "cacheClusterEnabled": false,
    "cacheClusterStatus": "NOT_AVAILABLE",
    "methodSettings": {},
    "tracingEnabled": false,
    "createdDate": "2020-04-24T13:50:18-07:00",
    "lastUpdatedDate": "2020-04-27T01:36:12-07:00"
}
```

I found this solution by checking the network call made by API Gateway console.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful, however I have to change only the throttling settings, not anything else, because the method might have other settings that override the defaults. Is there a way to tell it to get its throttling settings from the stage?

Comment: I do not think that it is possible currently. When method level override is mentioned ALL the settings are read from overrides and not defaulted to stage.